# How to guess an implied predicate?

Tags: syntax

The subject and predicate are main parts of a sentence. A subject can be omitted and easily deduced from the context, but when a predicate is omitted it is quite a challenge (at least for a foreign language learner) to guess what it should be. In Japanese I often encounter sentences without a predicate, which can be probably qualified as "phrases", but I always have a feeling that a predicate is implied but have difficulty to guess. A typical example from a female targeted website:

**MERY [メリー]｜女の子の毎日をかわいく。**

In the above phrase **毎日** is apparently and object and **かわいく** must be an adverbial modifier, but what is the predicate? する? なる? Something else?

Is there a general guidance how to guess an implied predicate in scenarios like this?

Answer (score 1):

**MERY [Mary] ｜女の子の毎日をかわいく。**

What is omitted in this sentence is "する" or "しましょう".
Most of the time, these sentences are some kind of copy-write and appear in the headline of an ad article or in a set of ad images.
You can infer this from what the ad article is trying to convey.